# How Can I create a Google spreadsheet with two sheets in javascript using Google sheets API?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a Google Spreadsheet with two sheets or 'tabs' Using javascript. I can Create a sheet and add a title to a tab, but I can only create one tab. I have tried to use the [addSheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet) property as well and it simply over-writes existing sheet. This is the data I'm trying to send as an example:

```
var data = {
  properties: {
    title: 'Data Sheet'
  },

  sheets: [{
    properties: {
      title: 'data A',
    },
    properties: {
      title: 'data B',
    }

  }]
};
```

Comment: This is not really a Google Apps Script question. Apps Script is a language based on Javascript that is used to create addons within Google Drive. I have proposed changes to your tags.

Comment: Thanks. First post...

Comment: @Jacob Ruleaux Before I answer, I would like to confirm about your situation, because I would like to correctly understand it. 1. You can use Sheets API. 2. You want to create new Spreadsheet including 2 sheets. 3. Your issue is the request body and you want the correct request body for it. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike That is correct. I can create a spreadsheet using the API via javascript but can only seem to create a spreadsheet with one sheet. I would like two. The request body does not seem to work in the above format. I have tried different variations.

Comment: I use this:
  $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/?alt=json&access_token=' + googleAPICreds.access_token,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (response) {
                        googleAPIHandler.saveSpreadsheetId(response);
                    }
                });
                console.log(googleAPICreds.access_token);

Comment: I resolved this. Stupid mistake on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing additional brackets around my data. Simple mistake:

var data =
                    {
                        properties: {
                            title: 'Data Sheet'
                        },

```
                    sheets : [
                        {
                            properties: {
                                title: 'data A',
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            properties: {
                                title: 'data B',
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                };
```